# How to remove the second digit after decimal point using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to remove digits after first integer after decimal point using javascript.

if the input is 2.183 then i want the output to be 2.1 how can i do it. i have seen Math.round and
Math.trunc(). but they dont work as needed.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Why did you tag your question with "reges"? This is built-in functionality in JS as part of the `Number` type: you use `input.toFixed(1)` to turn any floating point number `input` into a number with a fixed single digit after the decimal point. Note that this will apply standard rounding, so if that's not what you need, `Math.floor(input * 10) / 10` will _seem_ to work, but will also squarely force you into IEEE Floating Point rounding errors because there is no such thing as "0.1" in floating point notation, it's literally an impossible value.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, slight correction: that's actually going to turn the number into a *string* with fixed single digit after the decimal.

Comment: Sure, why else would you round a number other than for presentation purposes, at which point it's just a String?

Comment: For `2`, do you want `2` or `2.0`?

Comment: for 2 it should be 2

Answer (score 0):

Use the Math.floor method. By using value 10 here you will get the answer. Note that if you divide the value by 100, you will get the answer as 2.18

`let value = 2.183;`
`value = Math.floor(value * 10) / 10`
`console.log(value);`